# Jquery - get value of <td> tag that has rowspan more than one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a dynamic table that depend on quantity of abc1's column. 

In this example i have 2 rows in abc1 column. that has value is 18 and 23 
http://jsfiddle.net/SdN4L/

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
        <th align="center" colspan="3">abc</th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th>abc1</th>
        <th>abc2</th>
        <th>abc3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">16</td>
        <td rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td rowspan="2">300</td>
        <td rowspan="2">b</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>333</td>
        <td rowspan="2">31</td>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="button" value="Edit" name="edit" class="edit"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete"  class="delete"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" name="add"  class="add"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>322</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want to do when i click to edit button. it will show value of next row like 3 step.
i don't know how to do 3 steps. how can i do that. thanks

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    //1: get rowspan value of <td rowspan="2">edit input</td>
    //2: for (i=1; i < rowspan.value; i++)
    //3:     alert('text of abc2') = 23 and d and 322
    alert ($(this).parent().siblings().eq(7).text());
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what values you want to show. Which one is the "next row"? What are the 3 steps?

Comment: i try more but i can't do step 1 :(, can u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rowspan value easily:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).attr("rowspan");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the next row using

```
$(this).parents('tr').next()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SdN4L/5/

Comment: thanks u, i want to get each rows and i found it by your answer. $(this).parents('tr').next().children().eq(0).text(); thanks. But i can't get value of rowspan