# How to get data/value from <td> with dynamic rowspan

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post">
      <h4 class="title">REQUEST RESIN BASED ON PO CUSTOMER</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>PO Number</th>
    <th>Part Number</th>
    <th>Part Name</th>
    <th>Qty Pcs</th>
    <th>Material Name</th>      
    <th>weight Product (Kg)</th>
    <th>Order Month</th>
    <th>Order Resin (Kg)</th>
    <th>Save Order</th>
  </tr>
<?php
$prevMonth = $prevPo = $prevDo = $prevKeyResin = "";
$rowspan=$total_kage=0;
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT PCAP.id,MP.part_number,MP.part_name,M.name,MR.resin,PCAP.qty,PC.po_number,MP.cavity,MP.weight_product,MP.weight_runner,PC.month 
                             ,CONCAT (MR.resin) AS KeyResin
                             ,CONCAT (DATE_FORMAT(PC.month,'%M %Y')) AS KeyMonth
                             ,CONCAT (PC.po_number) AS KeyPo
                             ,CONCAT (MR.resin) AS KeyName
                             FROM po_customer_add_product PCAP
                             LEFT JOIN po_customer PC ON PC.id=PCAP.po_customer_id 
                             LEFT JOIN master_product MP ON MP.id=PCAP.product_id 
                             LEFT JOIN master_resin MR ON MR.id=MP.material_name 
                             LEFT JOIN master M ON M.id=PCAP.customer 
                             Where PCAP.active='1' AND PCAP.open_po_resin='0' 
                             Order BY PC.month ASC,MR.resin ASC ");
// fetch pertama, utk cari jumlah rowspan dan Total(Kg)
$rowspan  = $rowname = $rowpo = $rowmon = $total_kage = 0;
$prevName = $prevPO = $prevMonth = $prevKeyResin = "";
$arrTotal = $arrRowSpan = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
  $pcapid[] = $row['id'];
  $KeyName = $row['KeyName'];
  if($KeyName!=$prevName) { $prevName=$KeyName; $rowname=1; } else { $rowname++; }
  $arrRowSpan[$KeyName] = $rowname;
  $KeyMonth = $row['KeyMonth'];
  if($KeyMonth!=$prevMonth) { $prevMonth=$KeyMonth; $rowmon=1; } else { $rowmon++; }
  $arrRowSpan[$KeyMonth] = $rowmon;

  $KeyPo = $row['KeyPo'];
  if($KeyPo!=$prevPo) { $prevPo=$KeyPo; $rowpo=1; } else { $rowpo++; }
  $arrRowSpan[$KeyPo] = $rowpo;

  $KeyResin = $row['KeyResin'];
  $hasilshot = $row['qty']/$row['cavity'];
  $weight1shot = ($row['weight_product']*$row['cavity'])+($row['weight_runner']);
  $weighttotal = ($weight1shot*$hasilshot)/1000;
  if($KeyResin != $prevKeyResin) {
    $prevKeyResin = $KeyResin;
    $total_kage = $weighttotal;
    $rowspan = 1;
  } else {
    $total_kage += $weighttotal;
    $rowspan++;
  }  
  $arrTotal[$KeyResin] = array( 'rowspan' => $rowspan, 'total_kage' => $total_kage );
}

$prevName = $prevPo = $prevMonth = $prevKeyResin = "";
$results->data_seek(0);  // balikin lagi ke row[0]
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
  $Name = $row['resin'];
  $PO = $row['po_number'];
  $Month = date('F Y',strtotime($row['month']));
  $KeyName = $row['KeyName'];
  $KeyMonth = $row['KeyMonth'];
  $KeyResin = $row['KeyResin'];
  $KeyPo = $row['KeyPo'];

  $hasilshot = $row['qty']/$row['cavity'];
  $weight1shot = ($row['weight_product']*$row['cavity'])+($row['weight_runner']);
  $weighttotal = ($weight1shot*$hasilshot)/1000;


  $td_name = $td_month = $td_po = $ttl_kg = $ttl_kg1 = $ttl_kg2 = $ttl_kg3  = "";
  if($KeyName!=$prevName) {
    $prevName = $KeyName; $rowspan = $arrRowSpan[$KeyName];
    $td_name = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'  class='td-name'>$Name</td>";
  }
  if($KeyMonth!=$prevMonth) {
    $prevMonth = $KeyMonth; $rowspan = $arrRowSpan[$KeyMonth];
    $td_month = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'  class='td-month'>$Month</td>";
  }

  if($KeyPo!=$prevPo) {
    $prevPo = $KeyPo; $rowspan = $arrRowSpan[$KeyPo];
    $td_po = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'>$PO</td>";
  }

  if($KeyResin != $prevKeyResin) {
     $mulai = new DateTime($row['month']);
     $mulai->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));      
     $sampe = new DateTime('+7 month');
     $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
     $rangetgl = new DatePeriod($mulai, $interval ,$sampe);
$option = "";
  foreach($rangetgl as $tgl){
    $dateid = $tgl->format("Y-m");
    $dateoption = $tgl->format("F Y");
    $option .= "<option value='$dateid'>$dateoption</option>";
  };     
    $prevKeyResin = $KeyResin;
    $rowspan = $arrTotal[$KeyResin]['rowspan'];
    $total_kage = $arrTotal[$KeyResin]['total_kage'];
    $ttl_kg = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'  class='td-weighttotal'>$total_kage</td>";
    $ttl_kg1 = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'  class='td-poorderresin'>
    <select name='pomonth' class='select-field9'  required>
    <option value='0'>Choose Month</option>
    $option 
    </select>
    </td>
    ";
    $ttl_kg2 = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'>
    <input type='text' required class='input-field9' autocomplete='off' name='qtyorder' onkeypress='return onlyNumbers(event);' maxlength='6' onkeyup='oneDot(this)'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='unique' value='mrp_order_resin' readonly='readonly' required />
    </td>
    ";
    $ttl_kg3 = "<td rowspan='$rowspan'><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>
    ";
  }
  ?>
<?php
echo "<tr>
      <td class='td-id'>".$row['id']."</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>".$row['name']."</td>
      $td_month 
      <td class='td-po'>".$row['po_number']."</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>".$row['part_number']."</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>".$row['part_name']."</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>".$row['qty']."</td>
      $td_name
      $ttl_kg
      $ttl_kg1
      $ttl_kg2
      $ttl_kg3
      </tr>";  
} 
?>  
</table>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<div class="mid-popular">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
//*
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btnSelect").on('click',function(){
  // get the current row
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

  var col1 = currentRow.find(".td-id").html(); 
  var col2 = currentRow.find(".td-customer").html(); 
  var col3 = currentRow.find(".td-month").html(); 
  var col4 = currentRow.find(".td-po").html(); 
  var col5 = currentRow.find(".td-partnumber").html(); 
  var col6 = currentRow.find(".td-partname").html(); 
  var col7 = currentRow.find(".td-qtypcs").html(); 
  var col8 = currentRow.find(".td-name").html(); 
  var col9 = currentRow.find(".td-weighttotal").html(); 
  var col10 = currentRow.find(":selected").html(); 
  var col11 = currentRow.find("input[name='qtyorder']").html(); 

  var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3 + "\n" + col4 + "\n" + col5 + "\n" + col6 + "\n" + col7 + "\n" + col8 + "\n" + col9 + "\n" + col10 + "\n" + col11;

  alert(data);
});
});
//*
</script>
```

[result browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBo6C.png)
[only 1 id show and order resin (kg) now show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXG80.png)

this code no use connection to db

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {width:100%;}
th {background-color: #4CAF50;color: white;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {padding: 15px;text-align: left;}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
table#t01 th { background-color: black;color: white;}
.btnSelect {
    background-color: #f44336;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btnSelect:hover{
 background-color: #c93326;    border: 2px solid #c93326;

}
</style>
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post">
      <h4 class="title">REQUEST RESIN BASED ON PO CUSTOMER</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>PO Number</th>
    <th>Part Number</th>
    <th>Part Name</th>
    <th>Qty Pcs</th>
    <th>Material Name</th>      
    <th>weight Product (Kg)</th>
    <th>Order Month</th>
    <th>Order Resin (Kg)</th>
    <th>Save Order</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
      <td class='td-id'>99</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>ASMO</td>
      <td rowspan='7'  class='td-month'>December 2018</td> 
      <td class='td-po'>ASMO1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>ASMO-4-4</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>ASMO4</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>1002</td>
      <td rowspan='3'  class='td-name'>DELRIN 111 PA (NC)</td>
      <td rowspan='3'  class='td-weighttotal'>74.511</td>
      <td rowspan='3'  class='td-poorderresin'>
    <select name='pomonth' class='select-field9'  required>
    <option value='0'>Choose Month</option>
    <option value='2019-01'>January 2019</option><option value='2019-02'>February 2019</option><option value='2019-03'>March 2019</option><option value='2019-04'>April 2019</option><option value='2019-05'>May 2019</option><option value='2019-06'>June 2019</option>    
    </select>
    </td>

      <td rowspan='3'>
    <input type='text' required class='input-field9' autocomplete='off' name='qtyorder' onkeypress='return onlyNumbers(event);' maxlength='6' onkeyup='oneDot(this)'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='unique' value='mrp_order_resin' readonly='readonly' required />
    </td>

      <td rowspan='3'><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>

      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>101</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>YAMAHA</td>

      <td class='td-po'>YAMAHA1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>Y1</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>YAMAHA1</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>2000</td>





      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>103</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>DENSO</td>

      <td class='td-po'>DENSO1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>D1</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>D1-11</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>3000</td>





      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>98</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>ASMO</td>

      <td class='td-po'>ASMO1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>ASMO-3-3</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>ASMO3</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>1001</td>
      <td rowspan='2'  class='td-name'>DURACON M90-44 (NC)</td>
      <td rowspan='2'  class='td-weighttotal'>7.25425</td>
      <td rowspan='2'  class='td-poorderresin'>
    <select name='pomonth' class='select-field9'  required>
    <option value='0'>Choose Month</option>
    <option value='2019-01'>January 2019</option><option value='2019-02'>February 2019</option><option value='2019-03'>March 2019</option><option value='2019-04'>April 2019</option><option value='2019-05'>May 2019</option><option value='2019-06'>June 2019</option>    
    </select>
    </td>

      <td rowspan='2'>
    <input type='text' required class='input-field9' autocomplete='off' name='qtyorder' onkeypress='return onlyNumbers(event);' maxlength='6' onkeyup='oneDot(this)'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='unique' value='mrp_order_resin' readonly='readonly' required />
    </td>

      <td rowspan='2'><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>

      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>97</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>ASMO</td>

      <td class='td-po'>ASMO1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>ASMO-2-2</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>ASMO2</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>1000</td>





      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>100</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>ASMO</td>

      <td class='td-po'>ASMO1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>ASMO-5-5</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>ASMO5</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>1003</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-name'>IUPILON S 3000 R (BK)</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-weighttotal'>28.209375</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-poorderresin'>
    <select name='pomonth' class='select-field9'  required>
    <option value='0'>Choose Month</option>
    <option value='2019-01'>January 2019</option><option value='2019-02'>February 2019</option><option value='2019-03'>March 2019</option><option value='2019-04'>April 2019</option><option value='2019-05'>May 2019</option><option value='2019-06'>June 2019</option>    
    </select>
    </td>

      <td rowspan='1'>
    <input type='text' required class='input-field9' autocomplete='off' name='qtyorder' onkeypress='return onlyNumbers(event);' maxlength='6' onkeyup='oneDot(this)'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='unique' value='mrp_order_resin' readonly='readonly' required />
    </td>

      <td rowspan='1'><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>

      </tr><tr>
      <td class='td-id'>102</td>
      <td class='td-customer'>YAMAHA</td>

      <td class='td-po'>YAMAHA1</td>
      <td class='td-partnumber'>Y2</td>
      <td class='td-partname'>YAMAHA2</td>
      <td class='td-qtypcs'>2000</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-name'>LLDPE F-410 (NC)</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-weighttotal'>32.5</td>
      <td rowspan='1'  class='td-poorderresin'>
    <select name='pomonth' class='select-field9'  required>
    <option value='0'>Choose Month</option>
    <option value='2019-01'>January 2019</option><option value='2019-02'>February 2019</option><option value='2019-03'>March 2019</option><option value='2019-04'>April 2019</option><option value='2019-05'>May 2019</option><option value='2019-06'>June 2019</option>    
    </select>
    </td>

      <td rowspan='1'>
    <input type='text' required class='input-field9' autocomplete='off' name='qtyorder' onkeypress='return onlyNumbers(event);' maxlength='6' onkeyup='oneDot(this)'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='unique' value='mrp_order_resin' readonly='readonly' required />
    </td>

      <td rowspan='1'><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>

      </tr>  
</table>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<div class="mid-popular">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
//*
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btnSelect").on('click',function(){
  // get the current row
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

  var col1 = currentRow.find(".td-id").html(); 
  var col2 = currentRow.find(".td-customer").html(); 
  var col3 = currentRow.find(".td-month").html(); 
  var col4 = currentRow.find(".td-po").html(); 
  var col5 = currentRow.find(".td-partnumber").html(); 
  var col6 = currentRow.find(".td-partname").html(); 
  var col7 = currentRow.find(".td-qtypcs").html(); 
  var col8 = currentRow.find(".td-name").html(); 
  var col9 = currentRow.find(".td-weighttotal").html(); 
  var col10 = currentRow.find(":selected").html(); 
  var col11 = currentRow.find("input[name='qtyorder']").html(); 

  var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3 + "\n" + col4 + "\n" + col5 + "\n" + col6 + "\n" + col7 + "\n" + col8 + "\n" + col9 + "\n" + col10 + "\n" + col11;

  alert(data);
});
});
//*
</script>
```

How to get value from "td" with dynamic rowspan ?
already tried but no lucky.
already read on 
[Jquery - get value of <td> tag that has rowspan more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685907/jquery-get-value-of-td-tag-that-has-rowspan-more-than-one) 
[How to get the table row td's value that has a row span column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626451/how-to-get-the-table-row-tds-value-that-has-a-row-span-column)
,  but no same case
help me

Comment: The td (obviously) belongs to _some_ row. If you find the td you want isn't in the current row, then it's going to be in some row above the current row. So you need to loop through the previous rows in the table until you find the first row which contains it. That should be the value you need, I think.

Comment: @adyson , already tried , not working

Comment: your current code doesn't show any attempt at all to do that. If you have an attempt to follow that logic, please show us, and explain what debugging you did and where you think it might be failing. "Not working" is not adequate as an explanation of your problem.

Comment: @ADyson , https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBo6C.png

Comment: That's not code that's a picture

Comment: @ADyson , update  code with no connection db , so you can test what wrong

Comment: What's wrong is that it doesn't do any of the logic I suggested in my first comment. You claimed you had written code which attempted to follow that logic and that it wasn't working. But what you have shown doesn't do that at all, there is no code which tries to look and previous rows and find the td. It's not even close to doing that. It just looks at the current row and nothing else. So...did you attempt my logic, or not?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXG80.png ,  only show 1 id , how to get ID 103 , 101 , 99  and order resin (kg) , and next row show error " undefined"

Comment: Right ok I see. That's makes your intention clearer. Since you are generating the HTML manually through PHP, a sensible idea would be to give your target `<td>`s classes for their current month, and also give each button a class for the current month. Then you can easily link the button to all the TDs which relate to it.

Comment: I know ,but this dynamic rowspan..can you give an example with dynamic rowspan and get value ?

Comment: That was my point - using PHP you determine the correct rowspan. Therefore you know how many rows will relate to the same order, and you know which IDs those rows have got. Therefore you can give the IDs in all those rows the same CSS class, and you can put that CSS class as a data-attribute of the button. Or in fact you could just put all the IDs directly as a data-attribute of the button and then read from them - no need really to worry about reading the HTML structure at all.